# From xml to a list of cover requirement

Tags: python, xml, list

I would like to create a list from an xml file to know what is  my number of required employees at day d and shift s.

To do so here's an example of the xml:

```
<CoverRequirements>
    <DayOfWeekCover>
      <Day>Monday</Day>
      <Cover>
        <Shift>E</Shift>
        <Preferred>2</Preferred>
      </Cover>
      <Cover>
        <Shift>L</Shift>
        <Preferred>2</Preferred>
      </Cover>
      <Cover>
        <Shift>N</Shift>
        <Preferred>1</Preferred>
      </Cover>
    </DayOfWeekCover>
    <DayOfWeekCover>
      <Day>Tuesday</Day>
      <Cover>
        <Shift>E</Shift>
        <Preferred>2</Preferred>
      </Cover>
```

Here's my code to save the variables:

```
days_week_cover = []
shift_cover = []
preferred_cover = []

for cover_requirement in root.xpath('//DayOfWeekCover'):
    days_week_cover.append(cover_requirement.xpath('.//Day')[0].text)
    for shift in cover_requirement.xpath('.//Shift'):
        shift_cover.append(shift.text)
    for pref in cover_requirement.xpath('.//Preferred'):
        preferred_cover.append(pref.text)
```

Now how can i add them to create a list to get the format such that when I ask for monday shift E i get the value 2 like:

- Monday shift E: **2**
- Monday shift L: **1**
- Tuesday sift E: **2**
- [...]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.iter()` to walk the tree and use a state machine sort of thing to gather the data into a dict. This assumes the node order is always Day / Shift / Preferred, not e.g. Day / Preferred / Shift.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pprint import pprint

xml = ET.XML(
    """
<CoverRequirements>
  <DayOfWeekCover>
    <Day>Monday</Day>
    <Cover>
      <Shift>E</Shift>
      <Preferred>2</Preferred>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
      <Shift>L</Shift>
      <Preferred>2</Preferred>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
      <Shift>N</Shift>
      <Preferred>1</Preferred>
    </Cover>
  </DayOfWeekCover>
  <DayOfWeekCover>
    <Day>Tuesday</Day>
    <Cover>
      <Shift>E</Shift>
      <Preferred>2</Preferred>
    </Cover>
  </DayOfWeekCover>
</CoverRequirements>
"""
)

current_day = None
current_shift = None
preferences = {}

for el in xml.iter():
    if el.tag == "Day":
        current_day = el.text
        current_shift = None
    elif el.tag == "Shift":
        current_shift = el.text
    elif el.tag == "Preferred":
        preferences[(current_day, current_shift)] = el.text
        current_shift = None

pprint(preferences)
```

outputs

```
{('Monday', 'E'): '2',
 ('Monday', 'L'): '2',
 ('Monday', 'N'): '1',
 ('Tuesday', 'E'): '2'}
```

You can then query the dict as you would any other dict.